# Current academics exponents of (classical) liberalism

Tags: political-philosophy, sociology, politics

First of all, I don't want to cause polemic with the question. I know it's a delicate issue and I don't want to touch personal susceptibilities. My question is more on ignorance since I am from Physics rather than Humanities.

There is a pervasive discussion in the media about the new feminist wave and the renaissance of the new left. Most of the time "liberals" blame that the phenomena that we are seeing somehow sprang from the Frankfurt school. Once can more or less believe this if one listens to e.g. Beatriz Preciado or Rita Segato. It is also said that Humanities and universities are taken by this new left ideologies.

My question is, what are the major current exponents of the liberal wing in academies, and if these people have addressed the phenomena that I described in the previous paragraph. I can only think in the works of Hayek and perhaps his colleagues in Chicago and maybe in John Rawls (but I haven't read his works yet). As you see these are somehow "old" people that may not have impact on current generations.

Comment: Could you point to what Preciado or Segato say about the Frankfurt school exactly? I can not understand from your phrasing if the "phenomena we are seeing" (that the Frankfurt school is blamed for) are the renaissance of the new left, or whatever it is that caused the renaissance of the new left. So it is hard to figure out what you are looking for the liberals to address.

Comment: Can't speak for the poster, but...  Table 12, page 41, indicates that 17.6% of the humanities are Marxist.  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.147.6141&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Question is a bit vague and open-ended to me; there is a lot that might be of interest. Most of it is just punditry but something that seems like it might have a little bit of substance to it is [*The Rise of Victimhood Culture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rise_of_Victimhood_Culture).